# Error TabActionBarFragment repeated data [EDIT]

Tags: android, fragment

I have an app that has an `ActionBarActivity` and inside I have two fragments that represent each tab...the thing is I have a list on fragment1 with two values "teste" and "teste2"
But when I change to fragment2(tab2) and return to tab1 again it repeats the values on the list like "teste","teste2", "teste" , "teste2" how can I prevent this?

TabActionBarActivity:

```
public class TabActionBarActivity extends Activity {

String contextoId;
String BuId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_action_bar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label1);

    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> tl = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);

   tab.setTabListener(tl);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);


    String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
            tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setText(label2);
            TabListener<Tab2Fragment> tl2 = new TabListener<Tab2Fragment>(this, label2, Tab2Fragment.class);
            tab.setTabListener(tl2);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);


            BuId =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("BUId");
            contextoId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CId");
            Log.i("BUIdTabFrag", BuId);



}


private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;


        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
                        mActivity = activity;
                        mTag = tag;
                        mClass = clz;
                    }



        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // Check if the fragment is already initialized
                        if (mFragment == null) {
                            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                        } else {
                            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                            ft.attach(mFragment);
                        }


        }




        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             if (mFragment != null) {
                                 // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                                 ft.detach(mFragment);
                             }


        }




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tab_action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

hope you can help me

"EDIT"

If I do this:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag).commit();
```

it gives me an error:

```
log: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.icenterv2/com.example.admin.TabActionBarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
```

on this line: `actionBar.addTab(tab);`

and

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
```

this way it duplicates again

Comment: I tried to fix some formatting, but things <UserList> are missing in the markdown. if someone know how to format the properly please fix it and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your `ListView` code, it is in your `ActionBar`code in your MainActivity. You are not properly attaching, detaching, and replacing your `fragments`. I have had the same issue. Post the code for your MainActivity and I can help you

You need to replace

```
ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
```

with

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag).commit();
```

So your method inside `onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)` should look like this

```
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
         // Check if the fragment is already initialized
                    if (mFragment == null) {
                        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                    } else {
                        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                        ft.attach(mFragment);
                    }


    }
```

because as of right now it is "adding" the `fragment` into the container, giving you duplicates.

Comment: is this the only way you are inflating these fragments?

Comment: yes its my first time with fragment so im still getting familiarized with it

Comment: @RodrigoCosta sorry for the late response, I just got home. Test the edited answer